# Product search function not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to make a function in the CodeIgniter framework so users can search products from my database and display (echo) them if a certain product is found. 
The problem is if I try to search for a keyword I see a blank page and nothing happens.

Search controller:

```
    <?php


class SearchController extends CI_Controller {


    public function index(){
         $data = array();
         //load view
         $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }

    function search_keyword()
{
    $this->load->model('Search_model');
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->search($keyword);

}


}
```

My search model:

```
<?php



class Search_model extends CI_Model  {


    function search($keyword) {


    $this->db->select('product_naam');
    $this->db->like('product_naam',$keyword);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('products');
    return $query->result();
}

}

?>
```

My view file:

```
<h2>Zoek een cadeau</h2><br>
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="<?= base_url('SearchController/search_keyword')?>" method = "post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name = "keyword" size="30px; ">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value = "Search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</center>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: any error or only blank page?

Comment: Only a blank page when I try to submit the form

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
return $query->result();
```

to

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Also, you are not calling result page in function and passing data in view.

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $this->load->model('Search_model');
    $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
    $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->search($keyword);
    $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
}
```

Comment: Hello I changed the code and it doesn't show the blank page anymore but still nothing happens when I submit the form. The page just gets refreshed

Comment: Do you think there is something wrong with the function I created?

Comment: debug that function are you getting post data? in controller and model both place also where are you printing data. ?

Comment: Where should I print the data? on the view?

Comment: yes on view, where you want to print. just simple try this <?php print_r($data); ?>

Comment: Yeh but I don't want to print it like that, I want to print the data when you search the name of a product in the search bar

Comment: Yes but you didn't answer my question.. My problem was that my products were not showing when I submit the search form

Comment: okay no problem you can ask a separate question for it you can ask a question into questions here

Comment: What do you mean?